# How to finish this game

Tags: php

Im making a game in php. my question is how to loop this into 10 rounds and how to make this case-insensitive and accepts the first 2 letter word even if it is mispelled. Required to input the user to string. i managed to code this and dont know what to do next.

```php
<html>
    <body>
    <h1>ROCK PAPER SCISSORS</h1>

    <?php

    print ('<form action="" method="post">');
    print ('<p>Player 1: <input type="text" name="p1" /></p>');
    print ('<p>Player 2: <input type="text" name="p2" /></p>');
    print ('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="PLAY" />');
    print ('</form>');

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $player1score = 0;
        $player2score = 0;
        $draw = 0;
        $player1 = $_POST['p1'];
        $player2 = $_POST['p2'];

        if ($player1 == 'Scissors' && $player2 == 'Scissors') { 
            $draw++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";
        } elseif ($player1 == 'Rock' && $player2 == 'Rock') {
            $draw++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";
        } elseif ($player1 == 'Paper' && $player2 == 'Paper') {
            $draw++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";
        } elseif ($player1 == strcasecmp('Rock','ROCK') && $player2 == strcasecmp('Scissors','SCISSORS')){
            $player1score++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";
        } elseif($player1 == 'Rock' && $player2 =='Paper'){
            $player2score++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";
        } elseif ($player1 == 'Scissors' && $player2 == 'Rock') {
            $player2score++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";
        } elseif ($player1 =='Scissors' && $player2 =='Paper') {
            $player1score++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";
        } elseif ($player1 =='Paper' && $player2 =='Rock') {
            $player1score++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";
        } elseif ($player1 =='Paper' && $player2 == 'Scissors') {
            $player2score++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";
        }
    }

    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it case-insensitive use strtolower on the input to make it lower case and use lower case strings for comparison.
Replace this in your code:

```
$player1 = $_POST['p1'];
$player2 = $_POST['p2'];
```

With this:

```
$player1 = strtolower($_POST['p1']);
$player2 = strtolower($_POST['p2']);
```

You can also reduce the number of elseif blocks by using multiple expressions in 
one.

Both

```
elseif($player1 == 'Rock' && $player2 =='Paper')
```

and

```
elseif ($player1 == 'Scissors' && $player2 == 'Rock')
```

results in same action. You can combine both into one block with an OR expression like this:

```
if(($player1 == 'Rock' && $player2 =='Paper') || ($player1 == 'Scissors' && $player2 == 'Rock'))
```

To loop 10 times you can use a for loop like this:

```
for($round=1; $round<=10; $round++)
```

I recommend you to take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp, they have nice guides and samples for PHP.

Edit: bluepinto got a better solution for the structure using switch.

Comment: hi tnx for ur help . where do i put the for loop? @datagutten

Answer (score 1):

when in doubt of user IQ, limit choise with pre-defined answers, where possible, with use of drop down box, radio box etc.

wrote this quickly. if any errors i think you will be able to debug, but i think you will get the jist...

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['play']))
{
    $p1 = $_POST['p1']; //don't need to check if post empty, 'cause used has a default value
    $p2 = $_POST['p2']; //don't need to check if post empty, 'cause used has a default value
    $loop = intval($_POST['play']);
    echo $p2;
    switch($p1)
    {
        case 'ROCK':
            if($p2=='PAPER')$_SESSION['game'][$loop]='Round '. $loop . ' - Player 2 WINS!';
            else if($p2=='SCISSORS')$_SESSION['game'][$loop]='Round '. $loop . ' - Player 1 WINS!';
            else if($p2=='ROCK')$_SESSION['game'][$loop]='Round '. $loop . ' - It\'s a DRAW!';
            break;
        case 'PAPER':
            if($p2=='ROCK')$_SESSION['game'][$loop]='Round '. $loop . ' - Player 2 WINS!';
            else if($p2=='SCISSORS')$_SESSION['game'][$loop]='Round '. $loop . ' - Player 1 WINS!';
            else if($p2=='PAPER')$_SESSION['game'][$loop]='Round '. $loop . ' - It\'s a DRAW!';
            break;
        case 'SCISSORS':
            if($p2=='PAPER')$_SESSION['game'][$loop]='Round '. $loop . ' - Player 1 WINS!';
            else if($p2=='ROCK')$_SESSION['game'][$loop]='Round '. $loop . ' - Player 2 WINS!';
            else if($p2=='SCISSORS')$_SESSION['game'][$loop]='Round '. $loop . ' - It\'s a DRAW!';
            break;

    }

    $loop++;
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<h1>ROCK PAPER SCISSORS</h1>
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="play" value='<?php if(isset($loop))echo $loop; else echo 1; ?>'>
<p>Player 1: 
    Rock<input type="radio" name="p1" value='ROCK' checked>
    PAPER<input type="radio" name="p1" value='PAPER'>
    SCISSORS<input type="radio" name="p1" value='SCISSORS'>
</p>
<p>Player 2: 
  Rock <input type="radio" name="p2" value='ROCK' checked>
  PAPER <input type="radio" name="p2" value='PAPER'>
   SCISSORS<input type="radio" name="p2" value='SCISSORS'>
</p>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
    if(!empty($_SESSION['game']))
    {
    $game=$_SESSION['game'];
    foreach($game as $count=>$comment)echo $comment.'<br>';
    if($count==10)echo '<h1>END OF GAME</h1>';
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```